# Search if a value exists in a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I currently have this:

```
cart = [{"40"=>[{"size"=>"1", "count"=>1, "variation"=>nil, "style"=>"3"}]}, {"40"=>[{"size"=>"2", "count"=>1, "variation"=>nil, "style"=>"3"}]}]
```

How do I search this array and find out if "40" exists?

Comment: Exists in what way? Technically speaking, `'40'` is not a member of your array.

Comment: cart[0].first[0] == "40" now build that into a cart.each block.  I guess he's referring to the string-key "40".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#any](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
item_in_cart = cart.any? { |item| item.has_key?("40") } 
#=> true / false
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find if "40" is a key in any of your array items, you can do:

```
cart.detect{|i| i.has_key?("40")}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
cart.each do |c|
  if c.first[0] == "40"
    match = true
  end
end
```

or far cleaner

```
match = cart.any? {|c| c.first[0] == "40" }
```